# How to execute mysql command from groovy/java on windows

Tags: mysql, windows, groovy

I'm trying to import mysql databases from a file in a groovy script.

I'm trying like this:

```
command = """mysql -f -u ${settings.dbUser} -p${settings.dbPassword} -h localhost --default-character-set=latin1 ${settings.dbName} < "$tableDefinitions" """

commandArray[0] = "cmd"
commandArray[1] = "/c"
commandArray[2] = "start " + command

def Process process = new ProcessBuilder(commandArray)
                                    .directory(workingDir)
                                    .redirectErrorStream(true)
                                    .start()
```

If I output the command on the console it looks like this:

```
mysql -f -u root -pHelloStackOverflow -h localhost --default-character-set=latin1 test123 < "C:\Users\XXX\git\YYY\commons\sqlData\table.sql"
```

However if I do this all that happens is a mysql console window opens, and I'm already logged into it, but nothing was imported. If I execute the same command on the console it works.

I tried calling mysql directly instead of cmd, but then I get the error "cannot run command", "system can't find the specified file"

How can I import like that without the mysql console opening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
def command = [ 'cmd',
                '/c',
                'mysql -f -u ${settings.dbUser} -p${settings.dbPassword} -h localhost --default-character-set=latin1 ${settings.dbName}' ]

def process = command.execute()
proc << tableDefinitions

def out = new StringBuilder()
def err = new StringBuilder()
proc.waitForProcessOutput(out, err)
if (out) println "out:\n$out"
if (err) println "err:\n$err"
```

Comment: @Opal I believe so, as it is now a single parameter to `cmd -c`

Comment: It solved the problem with the extra console, and now I get an output if an error occurs. But if I add the file through the pipe (process << tableDefinitions) it just hangs. But thanks so far, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: @Fels is `tableDefinitions` a String containing SQL?

Comment: Ahhh...  try `proc << tableDefinitions.text`

Comment: I already tried.. The command IS executed, I can see the mysql table, waitForProcessOutput just never returns. And groovy was indeed smart enough to use .text :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a list and pass every single argument separately using `cmd /c` add the beginning. `start` is not required AFAIK.

It would be:

```
['mysql','-f','u'] // and so on.. then call execute()
```

Comment: I think it's the redirect causing the issue